# Movie where there's a scene with a vivisected horse in a lab

Tags: story-identification, movie

This movie was playing in the background of a bar I was in, at some point in the late 1990s. I wasn't paying enough attention to get the name of the movie at the time, but one particular scene has stuck with me, and I was wondering if someone might identify it.

The scene was set in a laboratory - at least, it was definitely either very white room, or very brightly lit. There's a horse in there, that's been (spoiler added for reasons of ickiness)

> vivisected; its body has been cut vertically into fairly wide slices, so its organs are clearly visible; and - slightly more horrifically, and the reason it definitely fits in this SE - the horse is still alive, so you can see the organs working.

I've attempted to occasionally try to find it, but unsurprisingly, any attempt to search on the keywords of the bits I remember does NOT help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like a scene from ***[The Cell](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0209958/)*** (2000).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cell):

> *The Cell* is a 2000 science fiction psychological horror film directed by Tarsem Singh in his directorial debut, and starring Jennifer Lopez, Vince Vaughn, and Vincent D'Onofrio. The film follows scientists as they use experimental technology to enter the mind of a comatose serial killer in order to locate where he has hidden his latest kidnap victim.
>
> The film received mixed reviews upon its release, with critics praising its visuals, direction, make-up, costumes and D'Onofrio's performance, while criticizing its Silence of the Lambs-inspired plot, an emphasis on style rather than substance, and masochistic imagery. The film was a box office success, grossing over $104 million against a $33 million budget.

[This article](https://birthmoviesdeath.com/2017/11/15/say-something-nice-the-cell-2000) mentions the scene in question:

> Then there is the infamous horse scene, in which Lopez discovers D’Onofrio’s child persona talking to a horse, only for the horse to get sliced into a dozen pieces by falling glass panels. The horse’s heart keeps beating, and we can see it through the glass as it stands upright, like a specimen on display.

You can view the scene for yourself in the video below.

Comment: I do believe that you're right! It's close enough to what I remember that I'm sure my memory is at fault....

Comment: *"The film received mixed reviews upon its release, with critics praising its visuals, direction, make-up, costumes and D'Onofrio's performance, while criticizing its Silence of the Lambs-inspired plot, an emphasis on style rather than substance, and masochistic imagery."* I laughed when reading this. Essentially, the critics are saying "everything that makes this movie unique is bad, but apart from that, it's good"

Comment: This reminds me of the [split cow](https://curatedwares.com/artworks-damien-hirst-arken-museum-copenhagen/) I saw at the Arken Museum, Copenhagen